# OpenLDAP vs Google Secure LDAP

Tags: ldap, directory

I work on a school (500 students + 50 teachers) and we have:

- G suite for education
- RADIUS server for WiFi WPA auth
- Moodle
- Another apps with auth (big blue button, Emby, Sinology, closed web, forms ...)

We want to use a directory to store everyone's credentials so that each student / teacher can access all of these applications with a single username and password.

I have researched on the internet and found two possible ways to do it.

- Use a LDAP server (such OpenLDAP) to sync credentials with all applications, especially with G Suite using Google Cloud Directory Sync.
- Use Google Secure LDAP as a directory to sync with another apps.

The second option is simpler to manage, but I'm not sure it will work with all apps. Which one should I use and why?

I know of SaaS solutions like Jumpcloud, but their price is too high for all accounts ($66000 annually)

Answer (score 0):

Brandon with JumpCloud here, not in any sales capacity. Your described use case does look like a possible good fit, though it would of course take a bit of research to confirm if we'd align with all your SAML and LDAP applications. I'd suggest setting up a trial account (free for up to 10 users, forever) to see what you might accomplish. And though I'm not in sales, I will say that the figure of $66000 annually sounds off for a school of 550 students and teachers. Our EDU pricing is steeply discounted.